# General question about prop.table function in R

Tags: r

I am using the following sample code to get distribution of patients with different lymph node (N stage) status in a given clinical dataset

```
prop.table(table(dataframe$Cohort=="A", dataframe$Nstage)) %>%  
  `*`(100) %>% round(2)
```

I get a result which looks something like this:

[image]

However, I would like me results to add up to a 100% and not divided into False and True categories. The result I am looking for should appear like this (just an example):

```
0     1      2     Missing  
20   60     20       0
```

Is there a way to edit the prop.table function in order to get this result?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share data using `dput` ? `dput(dataframe)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to edit the `prop.table` function to give you your desired result. If you want the sum of your percentages to equal %100, then take a subset of the Cohort "A" first and then tabulate.

```
with(subset(dataframe, Cohort=="A"),
   round(100*prop.table(table(Nstage)), 2)
)
```